# After inserting datetime created in PHP to MySQL table, no result is returned when same table is queried with same variable value

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin

## Problem Description

I have two tables in a MySql database which is intended to store form submission info. The first table contains contact info from the form, the second, user source info (i.e. IP address).

I am creating a datetime in PHP like so:
`$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Then, I am inserting into the first table (successfully) the contact form info, along with this datetime.

Now, what I want to do is get the primary key (auto-incrementing integer) from the first table which is associated with this datetime. So, I query the first table with this string: `` $db_query = "SELECT `unique_id` FROM `leads_contact_info` WHERE `timestamp` = '$timestamp'"; ``

Herein lies my problem: when I query the table from PHP, it always returns '0'. But, if I go into the first table in PHPMyAdmin, copy and paste the datetime value from a given row into the query, then run the query from the PHPMyAdmin interface, it does indeed return the correct value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm getting to the, "I'm about to throw my computer out the window and me with it," stage of frustration.

Best

#### NOTE: In the below scripts, I have control structures for error handling/reporting, which I have omitted for the sake of clarity. Suffice it to say, they work and are not the source of the problem.

### Original Script

```
// Create timestamp
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Create query to insert contact info into first table
$db_query = "INSERT INTO `leads_contact_info` (`unique_id`, `timestamp`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `company_name`, `business_type`, `website`, `phone`, `phone_ext`, `email`, `time_of_week`, `time_of_day`, `notes`) VALUES (NULL, '$timestamp', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$company_name', '$business_type', '$website', '$phone', '$phone_ext', '$email', '$time_of_week', '$time_of_day', '$notes')";

// Execute query
$db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);

// Create query to get primary key from last insertion
$db_query = "SELECT `unique_id` FROM `leads_contact_info` WHERE `timestamp` = '$timestamp'";

// Execute query
$db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);

// Create query to insert source info into second table
$db_query = "INSERT INTO `leads_source_info` (`unique_id`, `from_page`, `referrer`, `user_agent`, `ip_address`) VALUES ('$unique_id', '$this_page', '$referrer', '$user_agent', '$ip_address')";

// Execute query
$db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);
```

### Edited Script (following suggestion from @SetSailMedia)

```
// Create timestamp
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Create query to insert contact info into first table
$db_query = "INSERT INTO `leads_contact_info` (`unique_id`, `timestamp`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `company_name`, `business_type`, `website`, `phone`, `phone_ext`, `email`, `time_of_week`, `time_of_day`, `notes`) VALUES (NULL, '$timestamp', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$company_name', '$business_type', '$website', '$phone', '$phone_ext', '$email', '$time_of_week', '$time_of_day', '$notes')";

// Execute query
$db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);

// Get primary key from last query
$unique_id = mysqli_insert_id();

// Create query to insert source info into second table
$db_query = "INSERT INTO `leads_source_info` (`unique_id`, `from_page`, `referrer`, `user_agent`, `ip_address`) VALUES ('$unique_id', '$this_page', '$referrer', '$user_agent', '$ip_address')";

// Execute query
$db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);
```

### Debugging Attempts

- Unquoting `'$timestamp'` in both insertion and selection queries.
- Various date format conversions on the PHP end of things (again, the insertion query is successful).
- Added while loop with sleep(1) on selection query (while result from query == 0).
- Tried using both `$mysqli->insert_id` and `mysqli_insert_id($db_connection)` to retrieve value of unique ID in first table. Both return 1 on first and follow up executions of the script (in other words, data is inserted into the second table with the unique ID of 1, which doesn't match the actual auto-incremented value of the most recent record in the first table).

## Workaround (Not A Solution To The Original Problem)

After many attempts, I finally decided to opt for a workaround for this particular problem. That said, I'd like to leave the question open in case someone comes up with an answer or otherwise has the solution. Thanks to all who tried to help, especially @SetSailMedia.

As a workaround, I changed the DATETIME field in the first table to a TIMESTAMP, and set it to default to the current timestamp. Then, I increased the size of the primary key field to, and in PHP, created a custom integer unique ID via `$unique_id = time() + rand(1, 999999999)`. I checked (via a while loop) to make sure that this unique ID did not already exist in the first table, then fired off the insertion query. Finally, I inserted into the second table with the same value as a unique ID.

Again, this is not a solution to the original problem, and I for one am curious to see what the issue is here, but I simply must move on with this project. I do hope someone else finds the information and efforts herein to be useful.

Comment: The format in your table is the same format that are you inserting?

Comment: show how you fetch/display the value as well.

Comment: @bicho Yes, no modifications are being made

Comment: @MarcB I assume you're talking about the selection query...

Comment: @MarcB ``$db_query = "SELECT `unique_id` FROM `leads_contact_info` WHERE `timestamp` = '$timestamp'"; $db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);`` which returns 0 each time.

Comment: and how you run it, and how you fetch a row, and how you display data from that row.

Comment: can you post an example of a date stored in the database? (the one you copy from phpmyadmin)
and, can you post the output of `var_dump($db_query)`?

Comment: @Z-WolF And here is the variable dump from `$db_query_result` after the call: `object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: I think I may know what it is: it just occurred to me that the script might be querying the table BEFORE the info is actually inserted. I'm going to add a delay between the two queries, and post the results.

Comment: if the last row inserted is at the 21:25:52 then there should be no record that match 23:00:31, since it doesn't exists any record with a time of 23:00:31. If you are using "=" you need to be specific to the second (at least is not a epoch type).
What exactly do you need?
The last record of that day?
The first record of that day?
The record closest to the timestamp?
The same timestamp you used to insert a record you are using it to retrieve the record in the same code block?

Comment: @Z-WolF I am querying on the exact same timestamp (created in PHP, in the MySQL datetime format), in the same script, immediately after inserting the new record.

Comment: I did just try: `// Execute query
     $db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);
     
     while(!$db_query_result || $db_query_result == 0)
     {
      sleep(0.5);
      $db_query_result = $db_connection->query($db_query);
     }`, which I was fairly certain was going to work, but it didn't :(

Comment: At this point, I'm ready to just pop an auto-incrementing unique ID on both tables, but I really would hate to do that. I feel like there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: Before that, can you post the query where you insert the record or better yet, edit you question with the complete code where you insert and retrieve the records (if you say is in the same script).

Comment: @Z-WolF Was just about to do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) (or equivalent function in your database abstraction layer)? This returns the primary key after a successful insert.

Comment: To be honest, up until now, I wasn't aware of it. Anyhow, I just implemented it (commenting out my existing selection structure) with `// Get primary key from last query
     $unique_id = mysqli_insert_id();`. Sadly, it didn't work: the insertion into the second table did complete, but the value of $unique_id was (see above) still 0!

Comment: If you `var_dump( mysqli_insert_id() );` does it output 0, or does it output another value? Can you tell me what data type the column is on table 2, where the result of insertion is always 0?

Comment: @WatermarkBranding and also, can you share the line of code where you initiate the `$db_connection` variable?

Comment: I cannot show the values of the variables used in the  initialization of the `$db_connection` variable (for obvious reasons), but here it is: `$db_connection   = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, 
              $db_username, 
              $db_password,
              $db_database);`

Comment: The datatype of the second column is DATETIME.

Comment: @WatermarkBranding can you try replacing with this code:

`$unique_id = $db_connection->insert_id;` (see here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you: GoDaddy is having issues. Anyhow, `$db_connection->insert_id` caused an error. Tried the two formats from the link you provided, but both returned 1 (see updates to "Debugging Attempts" above.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your answers in the comments and the code you posted i see where is the problem:

-In the first table you insert the record with a null value in the unique_id field and then you tried to retrieve this unique id but you dont get a result.

-Then you posted this:

> At this point, I'm ready to just pop an auto-incrementing unique ID on both tables, but I really would hate to do that. I feel like there is a solution to this problem.

There lies your problem, if you can pass a null in unique_id an the insert is a success but that field isn't autonumeric then that field is not_null and if thats the case it is also not the primary key.

Of course the SELECT fails because theres nothing to return and also the mysqli_insert_id because there are not autonumerics in the first table.

If you dont want or cant use a autonumeric then look at the [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function. The second table does not need any modification.

Comment: The field `unique_id` in the first table is an INT(11), auto-incrementing, and is set as the primary key. `unique_id` in the second table is set as a foreign key, does not auto-increment, and has the same datatype and size.

Comment: As far as passing in NULL as a value for the primary key field in the first table, I had read in more than one place that while this is not necessary, it is considered a best practice.

Comment: Finally, I will try the uniqid() function that you mentioned. This does seem promising, and I hope it helps me solve my dilemma. That being said, if it does work, can I really mark it as the answer (it doesn't solve the behavior noted in the original problem)?

Comment: I (or you if got enough rep) can edit it to reflect the useful answer :)